# CSS hover "through" element without blocking click

Tags: css

**note: I do not have access to the HTML or javascript code**

I am using the excellent Chrome plugin, [Web Override](http://weboverride.com/), to improve usability on a vendor site my company uses.  I am only looking for CSS solutions (or possibly js/jq scripts I can sideload).

I'm trying to set table rows to highlight on hover, which is easy enough:

```
#task-list-main-table tr:hover {
    background-color: lightyellow;
}
```

The problem is that there is a little button that appears on each row when you hover over it.  This means if I hover over the button, the corresponding row is not highlighted.

Good:

[image]

Bad:

[image]

I know I could use `pointer-events:none` but then I can no longer click on the button, which I need to be able to do.

So, **is there any way in CSS to "pass through" hover events without affecting click events?**

Comment: Structurally, is this button a child of the row you're attempting to highlight?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  It's at a higher level in the document and it's just hidden/shown and `top` is adjusted on row hover.

Comment: Are you able to use JS, just not the stuff used to show the button?

Comment: Yes, Web Override does support JS. So technically, yes.

Comment: @Scott In that case you may be able to use a script that adds a class once the mouse cursor's x & y fall within the boundaries of the element, and the class is removed when it exits. That way the box wouldn't be looking for the cursor to hover it per-say, the javascript would just check "is the cursor within the boundaries of the row".

Comment: @Scott what is the class of the button that is blocking the hover?

Comment: `task-tools-wrap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a pretty convoluted method, but if you have the ability to inject javascript, this function will check if your mouse is overlapping whatever element you supply as the selector.

https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/aegybp6n/8/

```
//Change this value to desired element
var hoverElement = "td";

//Change this value to the class you'd like to add when hovering
var addClass = "hover";

function getOffset( el ) {
    var _x = 0;
    var _y = 0;
    while( el && !isNaN( el.offsetLeft ) && !isNaN( el.offsetTop ) ) {
        _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
        _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
        el = el.offsetParent;
    }
    return { top: _y, left: _x };
}

function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
}

function overlapListener(element, x, y, classToAdd) {
   var eTop = getOffset(element).top;
   var eLeft = getOffset(element).left;
   var eBottom = eTop + element.clientHeight;
   var eRight = eLeft + element.clientWidth;
   if (x <= eRight && x >= eLeft && y <= eBottom && y >= eTop) {
      if (!hasClass(element, classToAdd)) {
         element.className = classToAdd;
      }
   } else {
      if (hasClass(element, classToAdd)) {
         element.className = "";
      }
   }
}

var elementList = document.querySelectorAll(hoverElement);

document.onmousemove=function(e){
   [].forEach.call(elementList, function(b) {
       overlapListener(b, e.clientX, e.clientY, addClass)
   });
};
```

I'm sure there are some JS gurus around here that could write you something a bit less obfuscated, however I found this to be a good practice exercise for myself. I chose to write it in vanilla JS as I'm unsure of what your limitations are, although JQuery could substantially reduce the amount of needed code.

Comment: I know you're working on it. If it helps, here is a simulation of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/scottbeeson/aegybp6n/4/

Comment: @Scott So something like this, perhaps? https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/aegybp6n/6/ - If this works and you *can* use jQuery, let me know I can slim it down quite a bit.

Comment: Clearly works in your fiddle, but doesn't work on the site for some reason :(

Comment: Where is it being injected? I have the Fiddle set up to be at the end of the `body`, though I can re-organize if it's being put in the `head`, for example.

Comment: html/body/table/tbody/tr/td/<div class=task-tools-wrap>

Comment: This page is a nested table nightmare.

Comment: I meant the JavaScript. When you include the script written above, where does it actually get put into the page? Also, incase it's easier, the first line where I have `"td"` actually accepts standard selectors. You can do `"#myId"` for IDs, or `".myClass"` for classes, etc.

Comment: Yeah, I updated the selector accordingly.  I'm not actually sure where/how Web Override injects the javascript. When I search for it in Chrome Dev Tools it shows two results in `debugger:///VM34995`

Comment: [**Here**](https://jsfiddle.net/tr_santi/aegybp6n/8/) is a version that will run in the `<head>`. Let's see if it gets us any closer.

Comment: Same result, sorry. It adds the highlight class appropriately but removes it when hovering over the tools button.

Comment: Are you getting console errors? It sounds like yours may just be using the `:hover` class instead of the actual javascript.

Comment: No console errors, but you were right about the `:hover` selector (edited)